# Promise Pending airtable

Tags: node.js, promise, airtable

I'm working with the airtable API, node js

- I have a table called mentors
- I have a second table called jobs
- I use a find function which will return the job name for each mentor
- I return records so I could pass it to my view
- I got promise pending. r

```
    router.get('/',function(req, res, next) {

      const title= 'test'

      const getRecords = async () => {

        const records = await mentors
          .select({maxRecords: 6, view: "Grid view"})
          .eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
            records.forEach(function(records) {
              jobs.find(records.fields["Quel est votre métier actuel"], function(err, record) {
                if (err) { console.error("Big Error",err); return; }
                records.fields.job = record.fields.Job;
                return records
              });    
            });
          });
          fetchNextPage();    
        }

        getRecords()
           .then(function(records) {   
             console.log(records)
            res.render('index',{title: title, records}); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Does `eachPage` return a promise for when the callbacks are done? Also you're never really waiting for the `jobs.find` callback.

Comment: The `fetchNextPage()` call seems to be on the wrong indentation level.